# Merge data pattern in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have around 6TBs of data in hdfs partitioned as hdfs://products/yyyy/mm/dd/hh
lets call it dataset1.
and I have daily data size of around 5GB lets call it dataset2 that I need to Insert/Update into 6TB based on a join condition..

Tasks that I am trying to achieve are following

1. Search 6TB files and find customer ids that are present in 5GB files. If a record is found update it with the new record.
2. If a record is not found, then write it to hdfs partitioned as hdfs://products/yyyy/mm/dd/hh

I need to use Spark to achieve this, my question is, will it be performant to read 6TB every day just to find customer ids that are present in 5GB size files.

Can you suggest an alternative Merge Pattern using Spark?

Answer (score 0):

The architecture of a "big data" use case like this could be the subject of a book.

In fact, it has been--*Big Data* by [Nathan Marz](https://twitter.com/nathanmarz?lang=en), formerly of Twitter. Learn more about his Lambda Architecture [here](http://lambda-architecture.net/).

At a really high, oversimplified level, the idea is to put all your raw data (the source of truth) in the "batch layer" (*e.g.* HDFS), run analytics (*e.g.* with Spark) to precompute "batch views"--essentially indexes of the data--into a "serving layer", and then process new data in the "speed layer" by running analytics, creating views, and ultimately merging those data with the batch and serving layers.

It seems like this is the kind of architecture you should think about for your situation.

A simpler approach that is based on streaming rather than batching is the [Kappa Architecture](http://milinda.pathirage.org/kappa-architecture.com/) by Jay Kreps, formerly of LinkedIn. I actually prefer the Kappa Architecture, but if you don't have streams of realtime data, it doesn't apply.

I think you should get Nathan's book and read very carefully how the recent data that arrives each day into the speed layer gets merged with the serving and batch layers containing data going back to the "beginning of time." The case studies in the resources I mentioned should help you set things up in a way that works for your business.

Comment: I like the idea of immutable master data. But the batch view processing still processes all data every time batch process runs and I can imagine it will take a long time to execute as the logic gets more complicated. I would still ask the same question is there an elegant Merge pattern one should use in Spark to Merge data in batch data processing?

Comment: You misunderstand the architecture. The batch layer *does not* process all data every time. The batch layer and the serving layer would operate basically once with all the data you currently have. Then all *new data* would be handled by the speed layer, and there is a process that takes the *new* data and indexes and merges that new increment with the data in the batch and serving layers. I know it's complicated, but obviously the Lambda Architecture wouldn't have a book and numerous implementations if it was slow and inefficient.

Comment: Lets take a concrete example. I have 6TB files with attributes such as EventDate,TransactionType, BalanceBeforeAdjustment,Final Balance.  I receive around 5GB size files daily with new records as well as updates to existing records.  I can partition New and Batch data on the Merge Key to reduce the amount of data that needs to be processed by Spark. but I need to process this data further apply analytical functions, join with other data and finally produce something like a fact table that end users can make sense of. Fact table would also require incremental loading.